# How to load data into Excel Userform Listbox from Access form directly?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, userform

I want to load some data from Access into Excel Userform ListBox. What I am doing now is creating `ADODB.Connection` to connect access and create `ADODB.Recordset` to store data, firstly. Secondly, I use `Range("xx").CopyFromRecordset` to copy the data to excel sheet. Thirdly, name that excel range as "`ResultSet`". Fourthly, use `Me.ListName.RowSource="ResultSet"` to copy data from excel sheet to ListBox.

As you can see, I use four steps to finish this job. Is there a way to skip step 2 and step 3, copying data from Access to ListBox directly?

Thanks

Comment: Is the recordset dynamic? I'd use Excel's external data tools to import the Access data into a spreadsheet in Excel. If selections on your userform are often changing the listbox source, this might not be a performance enhancer. If the recordset is more or less static, you could set the external source and listbox source once and use Excel's refresh button any time you need to update the data source. If you are linking to a table, use the "From Access" option, otherwise "From Other Sources" > "From Microsoft Query" should give you access to either tables or queries.

Comment: @ChristopherD. Thanks for the reply. Yes, it is dynamic. Besides, the reason that I want to skip step 2 and step 3 is I don't want users see the data in Excel. I just want the data showing in Listbox.

Answer (score 1):

I found one article. Below is the code and this is the [link](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/populate_userform_listbox_or_combobox.html).

```
  With rs
    .MoveLast
    NoOfRecords = .RecordCount
    .MoveFirst
  End With
  'Set the number of ListBox columns = number of fields in the recordset
  ListBox1.ColumnCount = rs.Fields.Count
  'Load the listbox with the retrieved records
  ListBox1.Column = rs.GetRows(NoOfRecords)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**For a single column listbox**

Try to manually edit the list using a loop:

```
Me.ListName.Clear 'First clear existing list
With Me.ListName
    While rs.EOF = False
        .AddItem rs.Fields(0).Value
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
End With
```

Swap that code with steps 2-4.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One question: it is loading data one cell after another, right? Will it be slower than `CopyFromRecordset`?

Comment: @kzhang12 Yes it loads one at a time and is slower than your current code. Depending on the size, maybe not perceptibly slower, but copying the recordset or linking to external data would be faster. You can try setting your listbox source to the recordset directly, but I've never tried that before. I use Access instead of userforms, so this is a bit outside of my experience.